# Weird Ghidra decompiler output for simple crack me

Tags: ghidra

Here is the Ghidra decompiler output for a crackme problem. Specifically, [this one](https://crackmes.one/crackme/5d443bb533c5d444ad3018b3):
Code:

```
undefined8 entry(undefined8 param_1,char *param_2)
{
  int iVar1;
  size_t sVar2;
  char *pcVar3;
  char *pcVar4;
  char local_118 [9];
  char local_10f;
  long local_10;

  local_10 = *(long *)___stdinp;
  _strcspn("Enter the password...\n",param_2);
  _printf(local_118,0x100,*(undefined8 *)_fgets);
  pcVar3 = "\n";
  sVar2 = _strlen(local_118);
  pcVar4 = local_118;
  local_118[sVar2] = '\0';
  iVar1 = dyld_stub_binder();
  if (iVar1 == 10) {
    if (local_118[0] == local_10f) {
      _strcspn("Correct!\nthe password is: %s\n",local_118);
    }
    else {
      _wrong_password(pcVar4,pcVar3);
    }
  }
  else {
    _wrong_password(pcVar4,pcVar3);
  }
  if (*(long *)___stdinp == local_10) {
    return 0;
  }
```

I'm having some trouble understanding the output.

1. the printf and strcspn functions seem to be switched?
2. the `local_10f` variable is never initialized, and yet is still used to compare to the passcode.
3. I know from reading the solution, that as long as the first and last characters are the same, and the length is 10, then the passcode will work. How does "dyld_stub_binder" check for length? Where do the first and last characters get compared?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your `Ghidra` decompilation went wrong. Are you using the last version of `Ghidra`?

The output that I get in the latest version is:

```
undefined8 entry(void)

{
  size_t sVar1;
  char local_118 [9];
  char local_10f;
  long local_10;

  local_10 = *(long *)___stack_chk_guard;
  _printf("Enter the password...\n");
  _fgets(local_118,0x100,*(FILE **)___stdinp);
  sVar1 = _strcspn(local_118,"\n");
  local_118[sVar1] = '\0';
  sVar1 = _strlen(local_118);
  if ((int)sVar1 == 10) {
    if (local_118[0] == local_10f) {
      _printf("Correct!\nthe password is: %s\n",local_118);
    }
    else {
      _wrong_password();
    }
  }
  else {
    _wrong_password();
  }
  if (*(long *)___stack_chk_guard == local_10) {
    return 0;
  }
                    /* WARNING: Subroutine does not return */
  ___stack_chk_fail();
}
```

Which makes much more sense. I would guess that your `Ghidra` version has some problems with parsing the `plt`/imports. Upgrade to the latest version and check again.

As for your second question: 
When you don't understand the decompilation, you should always go to the disassembly.

```
   100000e42        MOVSX      EAX,byte ptr [RBP + local_118]

   100000e49        MOVSX      ECX,byte ptr [RBP + local_10f]

   100000e50        CMP        EAX,ECX
```

You can see that there is a compersion between two bytes from the stack.

In this case `RBP + local_118` is the pointer to the stack location of the user string. 
`0x118 - 0x10f = 9` => You are looking at the last character (index 9 of the string is the 10th character). So the comparison is between the first and the last char.

Comment: I just installed yesterday, but after reinstalling it worked! Thanks for your help. (I also disabled MacOS's "protection" for opening programs from the internet). How do you know that local_10f is indeed 0x10f?

Comment: You can see it in the beginning of the function, just below the signature.

Comment: It looks like the issue is with Ghidra 9.1.1, actually. I had to downgrade to 9.1 to get the sensible version of this code. I'm so glad I came across this post, I had no idea what I was seeing.